# Is it possible to authenticate mobile devices in an ASP.NET webapplication using windows-authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, windows-authentication

I am working on an intranet-application that's using windows-authentication. This works great on desktop devices but I also have to include mobile devices, which are working in a different network than the Active Directory. So when I open a page that requires the user to be authenticated as a windows user, I get prompted with the login popup. Submitting the login-credentials as usual on a desktop PC does not work for the mobile devices.

Using forms-authentication you can simply set an authorization-cookie. Is there a way to do the same thing for windows-authentication or do I have to implement a workaround using mixed mode authentication (windows and forms together)?

Used Technologies:

- MS SQL Server 2008
- MS VS 2010
- ASP.NET MVC 3 - Razor View Engine
- Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC
- IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008
- iPad and iPod touch as mobile user-devices